# Is stack memory only for pointers and heap for objects?

Tags: c#, pointers, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Firstly, I'm currently working in C# and I've been reading up on memory management. So far, I've read through some great answers on stack overflow explaining the difference between stack memory and the managed heap memory. The majority of the answers state that by declaring:
`int x = 5`, you're allocating enough memory for the type of `x` within the stack memory.
I understand how this works as well as the scope of it, however when I read the explanation of heap memory, it confused me.
If you're saying `int x = 5`, since `int` is an alias of `System.Int32`, wouldn't `x` technically be a pointer to a new instance of the `System.Int32` struct? And if so, wouldn't it then be stored in the heap memory since that's used for instance objects.
In [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types) tutorial, it states (for the line `class1 cls1 = new class1()`):

> ... creates a pointer on the stack and the actual object is stored in a different type of memory location called ‘Heap’.

By this logic, isn't everything stored on the heap and only pointers stored on the stack? Examples being new instances of `System.String`, `System.Int64`, `System.Boolean`, `System.Decimal` etc.
I thought I understood it, however clearly I don't, so I would appreciate someone explaining whether the stack is only for pointers or which part I've misinterpreted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `System.Int32` is a struct, not a class. So, *as a local*, it will likely get allocated on the stack.

Comment: Keep in mind that the .NET CLR is changing, and the lines between "heap allocated" and "stack allocated" are continuing to get fuzzier.

Comment: That tutorial said: "The time it hits the new keyword, it allocates on 'heap'.", and when you use a struct (to my knowledge) you have to use the new keyword. So that's partially why I'm confused too.

Comment: [The Truth About Value Types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/)

Comment: The tutorial is wrong and incomplete.

Comment: `The time it hits the new keyword, it allocates on 'heap'` <= that is correct for that particular line of code as you are instantiating a reference type. If it was a more general statement about the `new` word itself and the heap it would be wrong (but it isn't).

Comment: @Nathangrad you don't have to use `new` with a struct. Just declaring one like `MyStruct foo;` will cause an allocation with `default(MyStruct)`. For primitives, you can do `System.Int32 foo = 4`.

Comment: @vcsjones Wouldn't the usage of a MyStruct method of 'foo' result in a NullReferenceException because it's not assigned to an instance of the MyStruc struct? (I would assume at least)

Comment: @Nathangrad structs cannot be null in C#. Structs are value types. There is no reference to be null. The C# compiler will probably error with "use of uninitialized variable" but that's just the compiler trying to be helpful.

Comment: Then by declaring, it would automatically be calling the parameterless constructor if it exists for that struct? Otherwise just creating a new instance of it?

Comment: @Nathangrad it behaves the same as [`default(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx). The constructor won't be called exactly, it will just be initialized to "empty", as will all of the fields.

Comment: I know you're asking primarily about C# here but as an interesting digression about computer architecture in general usually when we implemented method calls in MIPS assembly language we'd use the stack to get more register space and to save the caller's state - e.g. if we needed to re-use 3 registers that the caller had been using we'd push the value in those 3 registers onto the stack, re-use the registers, and then pop the values off the stack to restore the original caller's register state. In this case, the stack was used more or less for local variables.

Comment: @Nathangrad here's an example: http://ideone.com/Zn4Ngu . Note that class "C" declares a struct as a field, and never sets it to anything, but it and its fields are usable.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand that part, but then what if the type of 'foo' in the 'Frob' struct was a Nullable<int>? The response: http://ideone.com/CoDNZM

Comment: @Nathangrad The bits that represent the struct would be all zeros, which, for something of type `Nullable`, semantically means the same thing as `null`.

Comment: The nullable type was purely for testing, but in the case of http://ideone.com/s5uPgt where it's a string involved, that outputs as a null value. So if you wanted to use a method within the struct for that which involves that string (e.g .Replace()), it would come up with an exception I believe.

Comment: Example of constructor usage using the new keyword as opposed to a declaration: http://ideone.com/rTrJ2k

Comment: @Nathangrad don't forget about stackalloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following rule: if it's a struct (including primitive types) then it's allocated where it's declared, otherwise a pointer to an object in heap is allocated.

Possible locations are:

1. For local variables it's a stack. Note that physically values can be stored in CPU registers rather than in stack.
2. For class fields it's inside of contiguous chunk of memory allocated in heap for an instance of the class.
3. For static fields it's allocated in loader heap as a part of type metadata (сorrect me if I am wrong).

Warning: this is just basic, non-comprehensive explanation to have a basic understanding of what's going on. The reality is more complicated. Local variables can be hoisted and moved to heap, optimizer can eliminate them altogether, etc...

Comment: For *unhoisted* local variables, it may be the stack. See the Eric Lippert post linked to in the comments if you want to be precise.

Comment: Yes, hoisted variables becomes fields of a display (closure) class

Comment: And the stack may not even be used even if the variable isn't hoisted.  It may strictly use the register, or it may be optimized out entirely.

Comment: I've just had to google like 80% of the technical terms you've used in the answer, but I think I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check [Classes and structs (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx) to understand what is stored where and how:

```
int x = 1; // 32 bits holding an integer in the stack
System.Object bo = x; // 32+some more bits are on the heap to hold the "boxed" (wrapped to be kept on the heap) integer value
System.Object ho = new Object(); // some bits are created on the heap right from the start
```

In simple words there are two types of objects: classes and structs. The classes (reference types) are meant to be stored on the heap and have a pointer to them while structs are meant to be stored in the stack (the structs can be relocated to the heap though with a little overhead of wrapping("boxing") them).

If you really need/want to understand how CLR works in general, consider reading "CLR via C#" (Richter).

Comment: And then you can read ECMA specification if you have lots of free time.

Comment: If you wanted to add more, you should edit your answer. There shouldn't ever be a need to *directly* comment on your own (question/answer)

Comment: It's more complicated than just "value types are stored on the stack and reference types are stored on the heap."

Comment: @EJoshuaS that is what I implied.

Comment: `classes [...] have a pointer to them in the stack` The pointer isn't necessarily on the stack.  It *may* be on the stack, which applies to *any* value, as Joshua also pointed out also makes the second half of that same sentence wrong.

Comment: As I (and Joshua) said before, the rest of the sentence is still wrong.

Comment: Also according to how the question is written imho, @Nathangrad is learning C# and while it would not hurt to know that the jitter can enregister the value, it probably wouldn't help him a lot.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Yes, I am still learning. No-one knows everything though, so I would say that everyone's constantly learning in this field with all the updates made to technology.